# Select data, resample and join horizontally in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

`df1`:

```
    Id  Date         Remark 
0   28  2010-04-08   xx
1   29  2010-10-10   yy
2   30  2012-12-03   zz
3   31  2010-03-16   aa
```

`df2`:

```
        Id  Timestamp                Value  Site
0       28  2010-04-08 13:20:15.120  125.0  93
1       28  2010-04-08 13:20:16.020  120.0  94
2       28  2010-04-08 13:20:18.020  135.0  95
3       28  2010-04-08 13:20:18.360  140.0  96
                   ...
1000    29  2010-06-15 05:04:15.120  16.0   101
1001    29  2010-06-15 05:05:16.320  14.0   101
                   ...
```

I would like to select all `Value` data **10 days before/including** the `Date` in `df1` from `df2` for the **same `Id`**. For example, for `Id 28`, `Date` is `2010-04-08`, so select `Value` where `Timestamp` is between `2010-03-30 00:00:00` and `2010-04-08 23:59:59`(inclusive).

Then, I want to resample the `Value` data using forward fill `ffill` and backward fill `bfill` at `1min` frequency so that there will be `10 x 24 x 60 = 14400` values exactly for each `Id`.

Lastly, I'd like to rearrange the dataframe horizontally with `transpose`.

Expected output looks like this:

```
    Id  Date         value1  value2 ...  value14399  value14400  Remark 
0   28  2010-04-08   125.0   125.0       ...         ...         xx     (value1 and value2 and following values before "2010-04-08 13:20:15.120" are 125.0 as a result of backward fill since the first value for Id 29 is 125.0)
1   29  2010-10-10   16.0    16.0        ...                     yy
        ...
```

I am not sure what's the best way to approach this problem since I'm adding "another time series dimension" to the dataframe. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the problem on a higher level so I can figure out if there's an alternative to this approach?

Comment: Hi, Luke, sure, the goal here is to prepare data for a classification problem. I'm joining `Remark` which are the "labels"(dependent variable) to the time series data (independent variable), to make each row a sample with a unique `Id` followed by the corresponding time series according to the time (`Date`) of the event (`Id`) happened. I hope that helps to make things clearer ...

Comment: Could try a rolling between df1 and df2 with `pandas.merge_asof` using `Id` as the joining key and setting a timedelta of 10days for the `tolerance` parameter. Of course this doesn't solve everything but perhaps just a nudge in the right direction of the first few steps to achieve your goal

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: @kelvt Thank you for the idea, I will have a look!